# cx_freeze dll error compiling pyqt6 application

Tags: python, cx-freeze, pyqt6

I'm using cx_freeze to build .exe file for my software. Here is my setup.py file:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os

sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
base = "Win32GUI"
includes = ["PyQt6", "PyQt6.QtCore", "PyQt6.QtGui", "PyQt6.QtWidgets"]
setup(
    name="AIChatter",
    version="0.1",
    description="AIChatter",
    executables=[Executable("activation_view.py", base=base)],
    options={
        "build_exe": {
            "includes": includes,
            "packages": ["PyQt6"],
            "include_files": [
                r".\activation.ui",
                r".\chatter_view.ui",
                r".\tinder_icon.png",
            ],
        }
    },
)
```

Here is also my activation_view.py imports.

```
 import os
    import sys
    from PyQt6 import uic
    from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
        QMainWindow,
        QApplication,
        QDialog,
        QMessageBox,
    )
    from chatter_view import ChatterView
    from logic.licensing import Licensing
    import platform
```

When I ran this build, and opening the .exe file, I get this error.

[image]

The problem is I was using the same setup.py script for another project without any problem. How can I solve this problem?